# "__RequestVerificationToken is not present" error when I can clearly see it in Developer tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken, devexpress-mvc

I'm trying to a CSRF protection to an existing MVC4 web application which uses DevExpress grids.  I've added the Html.AntiForgeryToken() into the forms on the aspx pages (which contain ascx as partials containing the grids) and can see the __RequestVerificationToken  and it's value clearly in developer tools when a save is called.

I've tried commenting out all my ValidateAntiForgeryToken attributes bar one - I went with the delete post method for simplicity (And also to eliminate the DevExpress grids messing with it) and I still keep coming up against this error:

> There was a HttpAntiForgeryException
>
> Url: http://localhost:54653/Users/Delete/f86ad393-0039-44e8-beed-a66dbab9266e?ReturnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54653%2FUsers
>
> The exception message is
>   The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  Could it be that the error is non-descriptive and it's actually that the token doesn't match rather than that it doesn't exist?  In previous answers to this question people just say "oh, you have to add the token," which is obviously not helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you submitting the form manually through Ajax? If that's the case, you need to pass the anti forgery token as another parameter with the name "__RequestVerificationToken".

Comment: Not exactly.  I've tried the manual submit from the DexExpress grid but unfortunately the application I'm working on uses a combination of MVC action methods and partial views with DevExpress grids on them (old style, with .ascx files as partials) so I have to add tokens for both methods of writing back data.

I'm fighting my way through it at the minute!

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 : Make sure if your application is has https secure protocol. Please load in https.

Point 2 : In case of DevExpress you have to call in the below pattern.

`ViewContext.Writer.Write(Html.AntiForgeryToken().ToHtmlString());`

Comment: The application can be deployed on local intranets as straight http, and some clients use it as SSL.  This shouldn't affect the writing of an anti-forgery token though, should it?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of using ViewContext for writing the token.  I'll give that a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for days I had a thought - maybe the browser is stopping the cookie being written.  I did a search for dev servers and cookies not being written, and found that with Chrome and IE10 and up that there's problems writing the cookies.

I downloaded Firefox and tried it with that and it worked *instantly*.  I then reapplied all the validate attributes to the all the controller methods and the all worked, every single one of them!  Even the DexExpress postbacks seem to be working correctly.

I'll carry out more exhaustive testing, but for now, I think we're there.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. If MVC AntiForgeryToken is already defined on page where you are using MvcxGridView and you want to protect grid actions you should send this token back to server during grid client side begin callback event.

```
    settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "function(s,e) { e.customArgs[\"__RequestVerificationToken\"] = $('input[name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\"]',  $(s.GetMainElement())).val(); }";
```